# trying to convert txt data to csv columns

Tags: python, regex

I am having a small issue. The below code works, but when i put a /test1 and /test2 into the file and change `'/test1 (.*?) /test2'`, it doesnt see it in the file and except runs.

```
import re
with open ('test.txt') as f:
    fin = f.read()
    try:
        print(re.search('test1 (.*?) test2', fin) .group(1))
    except:
        print('Didnt find test')
```

My goal is to extract from a list of text files and push into CSV Columns that has text like this below where i would extract /J6 to /K6 as a value range. There is multiple different lines of /J6 to /K6 , each value to be put into a separate column in the CSV.

/J60000,0000,0819,0016,0356,-13,0363/K60013
,0012,0013,0875,-0021,00465,0120/L60089,0002,

I just want to understand is there a syntax problem detecting the / . I am trying to extract values between a value and another value .thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `re.split` function.

Something like this...

```
In [84]: import re

In [85]: inp = "/J60000,0000,0819,0016,0356,-13,0363/K60013 ,0012,0013,0875,-0021,00465,0120/L60089,0002,"

In [86]: re.split("/[J,K,L]\d", inp)
Out[86]:
['',
 '0000,0000,0819,0016,0356,-13,0363',
 '0013 ,0012,0013,0875,-0021,00465,0120',
 '0089,0002,']
```

Disclaimer: I'm not good with regex at all. I used this link as a reference.
https://www.dataquest.io/blog/regex-cheatsheet/

Comment: Thanks for that, Thats anice way of doing it , but when its in a file with more data it takes the whole file less J,K,L . I managed to get it to work , "\/J6(.*?)\/K6" . My answer I was looking for was that the \ hides the / , and allows it work.